# how to assign a statement only if two event fire together in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

    div{
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;      
    } 
    </style>
    <script>
    window.onload = function(){

        document.body.onmousedown = function(event){

           var mouseStartX = event.clientX;
           var mouseStartY = event.clientY;


            document.body.onmousemove = function(event){

                 var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
                 div[0].innerHTML = event.clientX + " " + event.clientY;


            }

        };

   };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code I only want my mouse cursor position to be fired only when I fire onmousedown and onmousemove event at the same time means that i click and drag around my mouse.

Answer (score 0):

There are other events for drag, try using:

```
document.ondragstart = function (e) {console.log(e)}
```

That will output:

```
drag MouseEvent {dataTransfer: Clipboard, toElement: a, fromElement: null, y: 98, x: 177…}
```